# How to tell if an IP address in Amazon's cloud is static?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Given an address (not owned by me) which is part of Amazon's [Cloud](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html), is there any way I can tell if that address is "elastic" (static)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell if an IP is static(elastic) or not. AWS publishes a list of CIDRs that it owns and updates it periodically, but no information on if the addresses are elastic or not.

If the address is owned by you, then you can call [describe-addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html) and check if the IP is in the output. But if you don't own it, there is no way to tell if the address is elastic or not.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides you the flexibility to get Elastic Ip addresses in 2 ways

if generated with Elastic Ip console, yes it is static and completely owned by you, unless you delete it or re-associate it.

If you are referencing to Auto Assigned Elastic Ip address with EC2/ELB, they are not static. you get  a new ip address everytime you restart the instance/add or remove the instance from ELB.

Elastic Ip addresses are associated to instances, which already have an IP address(static until instance terminated)

Comment: That's good to know. But say, someone tells me "we will access your service from IP address W.X.Y.Z". I can tell if that IP belongs to EC2. But is there any way i can tell if's a real static?